# How to insert data into pandas dataframe based on evaluating each row to see if data is there or not

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {
'item_number':['123243','123243','7987987','7987987','7987987','4323242','223340'],
'prod_name':['apple','apple','bacon','bacon','bacon','milk','eggs'],
'seller':   ['safeway','publix','albertsons','safeway','publix','safeway','albertsons'],
'price':['0.69','0.50','2.99','3.99','3.67','3.99','3.99']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I have a data-frame that looks something like the above. What i'm looking to do is, for each item_number, the three sellers (safeway,publix, and albertsons) each need to appear. If they don't appear in the current data set they need to be inserted and the item number and prod name repeated with a blank spot for price.

The result looking something like this:

```
d = {
'item_number':['123243','123243','123243','7987987','7987987','7987987','4323242','4323242','4323242','223340','223340','223340'],
'prod_name':['apple','apple','apple','bacon','bacon','bacon','milk','milk','milk','eggs','eggs','eggs'],
'seller':['safeway','publix','albertsons','albertsons','safeway','publix','safeway','albertsons','publix','safeway','albertsons','publix'],
'price':['0.69','0.50','','2.99','3.99','3.67','3.99','','','3.99','','']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need a way to somehow evaluate if each seller exists for each item number or to force that they exist with some kind of left join to a data set that has been built by adding each seller to each item number in some fashion.

I tried something like:

```
for i in df.index:
    for comp in compDict:
        competitor = df.loc[i,'seller'].lower()
        if competitor.find(comp) > -1:
             do something
        else:
             df.loc[i+1,'seller'] = comp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the cartesian product of *`prod_name`* and *`seller`* columns after identifying unique elements present in them.

Set the same columns as the index axis and reindex based on the generated `list` of `tuples`. The values not originally present in our original `DF` would be filled with `NaNs`. Missing values in *`item_number`* could be filled by grouping based on *`prod_name`* and taking it's only non-duplicated occurence whereas nulls in *`price`* would be filled by empty strings.

```
import itertools

idx = list(itertools.product(df['prod_name'].unique(), df['seller'].unique()))
cols = df.columns
df = df.set_index(['prod_name', 'seller']).reindex(idx)
df['item_number'] = df.groupby(level='prod_name').transform('first')
df['price'] = df['price'].fillna("")
df.reset_index().reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: with my actual data-set i'm getting "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!". item number is the unique identifier here and if i can get each item number paired with each seller, i should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what panda is but it would probably make more sense to use a dict like this

```
items = {
    123243: {
        'name': 'apple',
        'seller': 'safeway',
        'price': '0.69'
    },
    7987987: {
        'name': 'bacon',
        'seller': 'albertsons',
        'price': '2.99'
    }
}
```

Lookup with all data would be as simple as

```
for item in items:

    item_id = item
    item = items[item] # There are more compact ways to do this but eh

    print('Item ID: {}\nName: {}\nSeller: {}\nPrice: {}\n'.format( item_id,
        item['name'], item['seller'], item['price'] ))
```